# No module named redis on Pycharm

Tags: python, redis, pycharm

I'm running a python programm on Pycharm and I have this error :

```
C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/3_redis/twitter_filter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/3_redis/twitter_filter.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tweet_store import TweetStore
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\3_redis\tweet_store.py", line 2, in <module>
    import redis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis'
```

I put the screenshot of a Pycharm Windows setting, you can see project interpreter and `redis` package.
[Pycharm Windows setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xViHX.png)

On my `tweepy_store.py` programm when I write `import redis`, I don't see the `redis` package.

When I run a twitter_filter programm I have the error of course as you can see on this screeshot.
[Running error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRTBg.png)

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be solve your problem:

- Activate your environment: `conda activate SentimentAnalysis`
- Install redis package: `conda install -c anaconda redis-py`

Comment: How to activate my environment?  I run the script above on line command?

Comment: Thank you I run conda install -c anaconda redis-py and my problem is solved. Thank very much

Answer (score 0):

Install the package redis, after activating environment.

```
# Windows:
env\Scripts\activate.bat

# On Unix or MacOS, run:
source env/bin/activate
```

Then install redis python package.

```
pip install redis
```

Comment: Hi, could you please also include the steps on how to activate the environment and install the ```redis``` package. In this way, your answer will be more useful for the current user and future visitors of this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you conda do not find redis module. You can try download and import module manuelly and again. You can find an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_Kxg-EYvxM